# Manage quotes inside string VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, quotes, double-quotes

I trying to insert to Access Table some values that I getting from another table, the problem is that some values comes with quotes and double quotes inside the string, like this example:

```
str1 = "Non-fusible sectionalizing "green' low rise switch."
```

How can I manage quotes inside string in VBA for Access 2010 for can insert it into table?

Comment: Use parameterized SQL statements

Comment: you could Replace() characters or wrap in double quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From memory I think you just need to double them up to look like this:

```
str1 = "Non-fusible sectionalizing ""green' low rise switch."
```

You can perform a `Replace` on the string using `Chr(34)` - the `"` character:

```
str1 = Replace(str1, Chr(34), Chr(34)&Chr(34))
```