# Excel VBA automated pivot table creation from multiple dynamic consolidation ranges

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to automate the process of creating a pivot table from a dynamic amount of data tables, which always begin with a date above the table. CountExpos counts the number of dates in the data range, so that the code knows how many data tables it needs to input into the Pivot Table with multiple consolidation ranges. Then the code makes a string of data ranges based on where the first date begins, and adds the appropriate data ranges to the string  based on how many expo counts there are. It then builds a string (statString) that can be placed directly into the creation of the pivot table starting at SourceData, ending at version, and then the code should output the pivot table, but instead returns Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Even when I copy and paste the output of statString directly into the pivot table code, the pivot table is created, yet when I just type statString, the code cannot run. I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

```
Sub CountExpos()

Dim lastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orc Text")

For i = 1 To 1000
    If IsEmpty(sht.Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
    lastRow = i
    End If
Next i

Dim expoCount
expoCount = 0

For J = 1 To lastRow
If IsDate(sht.Cells(J, 1)) = True Then
    expoCount = expoCount + 1
    End If
Next J


MsgBox (expoCount)

Dim count
count = 0


ReDim expos(0 To expoCount) As String
ReDim rgs(0 To expoCount) As String

For Y = 1 To lastRow
If IsDate(sht.Cells(Y, 1)) = True Then
    expos(count) = sht.Cells(Y, 1)
    rgs(count) = "Array(" & Chr(34) & "'Orc Text'!R" & (Y + 3) & "C1:" & "R" & (Y + 12) & "C10"
    count = count + 1
End If
Next Y

Dim statString As String
statString = " Array("

For X = 0 To expoCount - 1
 If X = expoCount - 1 Then
    statString = statString & rgs(X) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & expos(X) & Chr(34) & ")"
 Else
    statString = statString & rgs(X) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & expos(X) & Chr(34) & "), "
    End If

Next X

statString = statString & ")"
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox (statString)






ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
    statString, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Sum of Value").Position = 1

End Sub
```

Right now the below code works for building a pivot table from the multiple tables, but it would need to be adjusted every time the data range changes. I cannot understand why statString is not working when it is inputing the same thing into the code.

```
Sub GrandPivot()

 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
    Array(Array("'Orc Text'!R7C1:R16C10", "Item1"), Array("'Orc Text'!R22C1:R31C10", _
    "Item2"), Array("'Orc Text'!R37C1:R46C10", "Item3"), Array( _
    "'Orc Text'!R52C1:R61C10", "Item4"), Array("'Orc Text'!R67C1:R76C10", "Item5"), _
    Array("'Orc Text'!R82C1:R91C10", "Item6"), Array("'Orc Text'!R97C1:R106C10", _
    "Item7"), Array("'Orc Text'!R112C1:R121C10", "Item8"), Array( _
    "'Orc Text'!R127C1:R136C10", "Item9"), Array("'Orc Text'!R142C1:R151C10", "Item10" _
    ), Array("'Orc Text'!R157C1:R166C10", "Item11"), Array("'Orc Text'!R172C1:R181C10" _
    , "Item12"), Array("'Orc Text'!R187C1:R196C10", "Item13"), Array( _
    "'Orc Text'!R202C1:R211C10", "Item14")), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Sum of Value").Position = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly an issue with quotes. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20400170/6481438.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding If statements for the number of expocounts, knowing the number would be between 12 and 18, then creating the pivot table grabbling the multiple data ranges from the correct spots, for each expocount. Not the cleanest way, but it works.